# CSS3 border-image doesn't repeat

Tags: html, css

On my website, a `<div>` has a `border-image`. I generated the code with the alignments using [www.border-image.com](http://www.border-image.com)

HTML

```
 <div class="header">
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .header {
    height: 75px;
    background: rgb(50,50,50);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px;
    -moz-border-image: url('img/border.png') 30 round;
    -webkit-border-image: url('img/border.png') 30 round;
    -o-border-image: url('img/border.png') 30 round;
    border-image: url('img/border.png') 30 round;
}
```

Tested on Chrome and Safari, the border image displays perfectly fine except that it doesn't repeat.

Why is this? I stumbled upon [an old Github thread](https://github.com/LeaVerou/css3test/pull/4) from 2 years ago which suggested that adding a javascript variable called 'Dummy' fixed this. I tried it... And it didn't work. So I'm guessing that's a joke for gullible people.

On a related note, is it possible the make the border be outside the `<div>`? The final version will have a white background making the white `border-image` invisible.

Weird bug, is there a solution? Thanks.

**Screenshot**
[image: A Screenshot]
*Each part of the border only displays once, at the corners. They don't repeat along the sides as expected. NOTE: I did not include borders on the corners intentionally.*

*Also note the background is* around *the border, not within it.*

***EDIT: This is the border-image I'm using*** [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIc58.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your image looking like ?

to not have background-color to lay under the borders, you need to use instead an inset box shadow , big size and without blur

```
.header {
    height: 75px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1000px rgb(50,50,50);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 15px 16px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 repeat;
    border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 fill repeat;
         }
```

[http://www.border-image.com/#{%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FpWUNoki.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A[0%2C0%2C0%2C0]%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A[15%2C15%2C15%2C15]%2C%22fill%22%3Afalse%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A[%22round%22%2C%22round%22]%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue}](http://www.border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3a%22http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png%22,%22linkBorder%22%3atrue,%22borderWidth%22%3a%5B0,0,0,0%5D,%22imageOffset%22%3a%5B15,15,15,15%5D,%22fill%22%3afalse,%22setRepat%22%3afalse,%22repeat%22%3a%5B%22round%22,%22round%22%5D,%22scaleFactor%22:3,%22setRepeat%22%3atrue%7D)

Comment: The `border-image` image I'm using is [this.](http://imgur.com/pWUNoki). The box shadow does appear as a background, but it is too indented.

Comment: Your image has nothing to repeat to show, unless you change coordonates : border-style: solid; border-width: 15px 16px 15px 15px; -moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 repeat; -webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 repeat; -o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 repeat; border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/pWUNoki.png) 15 16 15 15 fill repeat;

Comment: It works great! However, if I try to set it to `round` instead of `repeat`, the image becomes slightly larger and is pixellated. Is it possible to make it add more images instead of removing when it aligns? Otherwise, thanks for this great help!

Comment: i think that you should rework/adapt your image for the use you want :)

Comment: Well, I'm really new to border-images so I don't exactly understand everything yet but by tweaking around a few properties I got it to work!